# Using Oauth with Offline first Application (PWA)

Tags: oauth-2.0, progressive-web-apps, dhis-2

I have an offline first application build using AngularJS(and service worker). I am taking advantage of IndexedDB to keep my data when the application is used offline(without internet connection). My application interacts with DHIS APIs to sync data when the internet connection is available. 
Now I want to use OAuth provided by DHIS to authenticate my users. Also, I want to provide offline functionality so that users should be able to use my application without internet connection.

1. I want to know is OAuth suitable for offline-first applications.
2. How to authenticate users when they don't have internet connectivity.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation about refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)?

Comment: I guess, this is related only to Google API client library. I understand that we can get access tokens from refresh tokens once it is expired. Do you know of any scenario where an offline first application is using Oauth